# How can I create customizer with postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]

When I tried createsuperuser at terminal, I could make it.
Also I could see created custom user password is hashed.
But when I tried to create custom user. I could make it.
But password is not hashed, and I could not log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you are using rest-framework or pure django but either way you need to call:

```
user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
```

If you are using built in Django models and views for auth(register, login, ..) it is already done. But if you use custom user model you need to use set_password(). The best way is in create/save method of model form.
Example for [rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)